# Display Datepicker in Editor onload instead of needing the user to pick

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

currently I have this datepicker which will hightlight today's date on the pop up calender but the editor for the date onLoad shows DD/MM/YYYY instead of aotopopulating it when the page loads. How do I solve this ?

This is how I display my datepicker in the html file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date)
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I define it:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EditorFor()` method is rendering your browsers HTML-5 implementation of a datepicker, which requires that the format be `yyyy-MM-dd` (ISO format).

Change the attribute to

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")
public DateTime date { get; set; }
```

which will display the date in the browsers culture

Alternatively you can use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @type = "date" })
```

if you do not want to change the format that will be used in a `DisplayFor()` method.

Note also that `type="date"` is only supported in Chrome and Edge